# Finding a value with Epplus

Tags: c#, linq, epplus

I'm trying to use the code to find the address of a certain value in a Worksheet using Epplus and Linq. The value is in column D (4), but could be in any cell
However, the following error is displayed

Linq Code

```
var query3 = (from cell in sheet.Cells["d:d"]
    where cell.Value.ToString().Equals("CRÉDITOS")
    select cell);
```

Error in Results View:

```
   at ExcelTests.Form1.<>c.<button1_Click>b__1_0(ExcelRangeBase cell)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView`1.get_Items()
```

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to do a `.ToString()` on null values.

Comment: That was it..Thanks ever so much.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As `@krillgar` suggested, you should rewrite the linq statement to include the possibility of `Value` returning `null`.

```
var query3 = 
    from cell in sheet.Cells["d:d"]
    where cell.Value?.ToString() == "CRÉDITOS"
    select cell;
```